# Using my own code fragments in multiple projects: does this count as multi-licensing?

Tags: licensing, multi-licensing

I'm working on different open source projects, to which I'm contributing code which sometimes overlaps.

Does this count as multi-licensing (and if so, do I have to make note of this explicitly)? Or do I have to structure it so that at least one of the projects depends on the other, including license copying etc.

Obviously, I'm not planning to sue myself, but if the copyright of one of the projects ends up out of my hands somehow, I don't want it to affect the other!

Answer (score 3):

To my understanding, if you are the copyright holder of the code, then you have the right to provide that code to multiple people/projects under different licenses.

As each project gets the code under a single license, they can't choose which license applies and this is *not* multi-licensing.